# How to break flow of code in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, return, break

I am unable to break the execution of code using 'return' keyword in Swift language. Please suggest the another way around for how to break the code execution flow if need be in Swift.

Comment: Why is that the `return` keyword didn't break flow of code? Could you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

You can find in the [official apple document](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html) all the Control Transfer Statements available, choose what you need for your context..

> **Control Transfer Statements**
>
> Control transfer statements change the order in which your code is
>   executed, by transferring control from one piece of code to another.
>   Swift has five control transfer statements:

- continue
- break
- fallthrough
- return
- throw